# data from datagridview to Line Graph

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mschart, linegraph

I have two columns in my datagridview and I want my first column to be the X axis while the second column to be the Y axis in my chart.

[image: my datagridview]

it is suppose to create a line graph.

Comment: Is this in web app or window app

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @VijayRaheja its in window app

Comment: @KrzysztofBracha I already tried some codes but it only works for bar chart type not *line* chart type

Comment: Which control you are using for Line Chart

Comment: @KrzysztofBracha a button for the line chart

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

**Usually** there is no difference between line, point or bar charttypes; simply loop over the rows to add the `DataPoints`!

**But**  in your case the x-values (`timestampdata`) are all the **same**! For `Line` and `Points` charttypes this will mean that all `Points` get lumped onto the same spot. `Bar` charts indeed wouldn't do that.

If you can't (or don't want to) get good data you need to set :

```
yourSeries1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

Then all `DataPoints` will be lined up, ignoring the x-values.

Comment: i already changed my (timestampdata) so it will differ but it will still not work and it shows error. Is it due to my coding?

Comment: _Is it due to my coding?_ Which coding?? Which errors??

Comment: for (int i = 0 ; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1 ; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        int p = chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText, dataGridView1[j, i].Value);
                    }
                }

Comment: _Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Heade‌​rText, dataGridView1[j, i].Value)_ - Should probably be: `Points.AddXY(dataGridView1[0, i].Value, dataGridView1[1, i].Value)` and no loop over the columns!